# Fire an event when mouse has not moved for 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, settimeout, mousemove

I am a bit lost where to start here. How can I fire an event when the mouse has not moved for 10 seconds? Would I need to have a resetTimer when a mouse moved, and setTimeout to 10 10 seconds? Having trouble putting it together.

Comment: Sometimes creating a flowchart, digitally or on paper, helps me to break down the problem into steps, before writing any code. Click here for more info on flowcharts: https://www.zenflowchart.com/guides/flowcharts-in-programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a debounced function. You can read more about debounce [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/)

```js
function debounce(func, timeout) {
    let timer;
    return (...args) => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
            func.apply(this, args);
        }, timeout);
    };
}

const functionToRunAfterInactivity = () => {
    console.log("Mouse has not moved for 10 seconds");
};

addEventListener("mousemove", debounce(functionToRunAfterInactivity, 10000));
```

Comment: This worked! New function learned, thank you so much